# AutoFilter method failing

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

This sub routine has suddenly stopped working; new sheets have been added, but no change to this code. Any idea why I'm getting the message "Auto filter method of range class failed" Run time error 1004?

```
Sub Hide_Row()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("a6:HO499").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you add `Application.AutoFilterMode = false` to the top

Comment: As a note, you probably want to add a `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` somewhere towards the end.

Comment: @NickPerkins while that is better coding, the `ScreenUpating` will reset to true at the end of the code